# How to implement sampling in ns3?

Tags: networking, sampling, ns-3

I wonder how to implement sampling in ns3. What exactly I want to implement is to create a simple network of switches and hosts using p2p links. Then, setting a probability (lets say 0.1) for an specific switch and expecting that every packet passing the switch will be captured with probability that I defined earlier. (Pretty much like the sampling in sflow or netflow).
I browsed nsnam.org, and the only tool I found regarding my question is Flow Monitor which I think is not helpful for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to implement the behavior you want, but there is a solution.

Set up a normal hook to get all packets going through one of the switches. Refer to [the tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/tracing.html) to learn how to use the tracing system.

Then, use a [RandomVariable](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/group__randomvariable.html) at the beginning of your function to determine whether you want ignore that packet or not. The RandomVariable will need to be in global scope or passed in as parameter to the function.